# UIView with rounded corner and border has wrong edge color

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have a UIView and two subviews in it. The subviews have rounded corners and a border value. The issue I have is that the outer edges of the rounded border contain a thin line of the subview background color. I must be missing something??

```
UIView *outerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 320)];
[self.view addSubview:outerView];
outerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

UIView *innerView1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 320)];
[outerView addSubview:innerView1];
innerView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
innerView1.layer.borderWidth = 20;
innerView1.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
innerView1.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
//innerView1.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

UIView *innerView2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 0, 160, 320)];
[outerView addSubview:innerView2];
innerView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
innerView2.layer.borderWidth = 20;
innerView2.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
innerView2.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
//innerView2.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
//innerView2.clipsToBounds = YES;
//innerView2.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

Comment: It would help to include a relevant screenshot showing the issue.

Comment: I ran your code with a green background and this is what I'm getting -> http://puu.sh/89bjO/6e551e085e.png is that what you're getting? I'm not really matching up your problem with what I'm getting

Comment: I now see your error. I'm messing with the code to see what's causing this.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, and I don't see any easy way to get around it. Are you interested in a kludgy work-around?

Comment: Thanks for the pic Mike King. Stack overflow did not allow me to add a pic and looks like I needed more score to post it.

Comment: @user3386109, yes I would like to try your work around if you have any. Thanks!

Comment: @venkat557 Ok, I posted my kludgy work around.

Comment: That will do for now :) You are awesome, thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To work around the problem, set the background color of the subviews to `clearColor` and then draw the background color using the `drawRect` method of a custom view class.  Here's the code for the view class.

```
@interface WorkAroundView : UIView
@end

@implementation WorkAroundView
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGFloat margin = self.layer.borderWidth;
    CGRect  background;
    background.origin.x = margin;
    background.origin.y = margin;
    background.size.width  = self.bounds.size.width  - 2 * margin;
    background.size.height = self.bounds.size.height - 2 * margin;

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [[UIColor blackColor] set];
    CGContextFillRect( context, background );
}
@end
```

And here's how you would use the custom view class. The only real change here from what you posted is that the background color for the subviews is set to clearColor.

```
UIView *outerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(360, 200, 320, 320)];
[self.view addSubview:outerView];
outerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

WorkAroundView *innerView1 = [[WorkAroundView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 320)];
innerView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
innerView1.layer.borderWidth = 20;
innerView1.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
innerView1.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
[outerView addSubview:innerView1];

WorkAroundView *innerView2 = [[WorkAroundView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 0, 160, 320)];
innerView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
innerView2.layer.borderWidth = 20;
innerView2.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
innerView2.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
[outerView addSubview:innerView2];
```

Comment: This is a great answer

Answer (score 1):

add a bezier path around the corner

```
CAShapeLayer *subLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
[subLayer setFillColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
[subLayer setStrokeColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
[subLayer setLineWidth:1.0];
[subLayer setPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:imageView.bounds cornerRadius:imageView.layer.cornerRadius].CGPath];
[imageView.layer addSublayer:subLayer];
```