# How to get rid of thin border in a UIView rounded with layer.cornerRadius in iOS 7.1.1?

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a customized UIView that rounds its corners by using layer.cornerRadius like this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2.0;
    self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

How can I get rid of the very thin outer red circle?

[image]

Comment: Hi, Did you find solution for this.Because I am facing same using can you please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Well, a more efficient way to do what you need would be to copy paste this function in the .m file of your custom view and call it in the drawRect method:

```
- (void)drawRoundedViewWithFrame: (CGRect)frame color:(UIColor *)color
{
    //// roundCircle Drawing
    UIBezierPath* roundCirclePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect: frame];
    [color setFill];
    [roundCirclePath fill];
    [UIColor.whiteColor setStroke];
    roundCirclePath.lineWidth = 2;
    [roundCirclePath stroke];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but I specifically wanted to have this as a UIView, because I want to manually set its position in the Storyboard.

Comment: Well you can still do it. Except that the view will be empty on the storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Based on an answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073224/uiview-with-rounded-corner-and-border-has-wrong-edge-color?rq=1), I figured out a way to do this with these steps:

- Set the `UIView` background color to `[UIColor clearColor]`
- Manually draw a smaller circular background in `drawRect:`

Here's the `drawRect:` implementation:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGFloat margin = _borderWidth;
    CGRect background = CGRectMake(margin, margin,
        self.bounds.size.width - 2 * margin,
        self.bounds.size.height - 2 * margin);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [_internalBackgroundColor set];
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, background);
}
```

And the overwritten `backgroundColor` setter:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *internalBackgroundColor;

...

- (void)setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor
{
    [super setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    _internalBackgroundColor = backgroundColor;
}
```

---

**** Faster solution: ****

As [Kujey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3655445/kujey) pointed out, it's better not to use the `layer.cornerRadius` at all. Here's the `drawRect:` solution without the `layer` access:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGFloat margin = _borderWidth / 2.0;
    CGRect background = CGRectMake(margin, margin, self.bounds.size.width - 2 * margin, self.bounds.size.height - 2 * margin);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [_internalBackgroundColor set];
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, background);
    [_borderColor set];
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, _borderWidth);
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, background);
}
```