# Rounded edges of cell thinner than the top and bottom part of the cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

i have a strange problem that when i make rounded corner of cell, the round corner is thinner than top and bottom i just make this :

```
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 9

        cell.layer.borderColor = redCellColor.CGColor
```

[image: here is an example]

Comment: i have same issue , any help ???

Comment: You should try use BezierPath and something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14071921/790842

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get rid of thin border in a UIView rounded with layer.cornerRadius in iOS 7.1.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23891033/how-to-get-rid-of-thin-border-in-a-uiview-rounded-with-layer-cornerradius-in-ios)

Answer (score -1):

Use drawRect instead of applying corner radius.

Here's a similar problem, with solution :
[How to get rid of thin border in a UIView rounded with layer.cornerRadius in iOS 7.1.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23891033/how-to-get-rid-of-thin-border-in-a-uiview-rounded-with-layer-cornerradius-in-ios)